# Foreach variable value assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

Sorry for the question that might be repeated but I'm stuck with foreach loop in javascript.

```
    let fields = temp_deviceAllocation.devices.forEach(async (device) => {
    const fields = await device_model
      .findOne({ device_id: device })
      .select({ fields: 1 });
  });

  console.log({
    data: await this.getdeviceAllocationById(temp_deviceAllocation._id),
    fields: fields,
  });
```

I check by logging fields values but it shows undefined here and when I separately logging out these values in foreach then it will display values. I tried return values within foreach but it still showed empty.

Please correct me if I miss something.

Comment: Returning a value from the inner forEach function does nothing.  `let fields = something.forEach(...)` fields will be undefined.  Foreach returns nothing.  Use map instead.

Comment: I use map but query inside map does not work as in foreach loop and array it return is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default forEach is async unaware, thereby firing multiple calls without awaiting for the promise to resolve first. You should hence avoid using await inside forEach and instead could use the for of loop.
I think this should work, from what I could figure out from your codeblock :

```
const deviceFields = []
for(const device of temp_deviceAllocation.devices){    
   const fields = await device_model
     .findOne({ device_id: device })
     .select({ fields: 1 });
   });
   deviceFields.push(fields)
}
console.log(deviceFields)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    let fields = temp_deviceAllocation.devices.forEach(async (device) => {
       return await device_model
      .findOne({ device_id: device })
      .select({ fields: 1 });
  });

  console.log({
    data: await this.getdeviceAllocationById(temp_deviceAllocation._id),
    fields: fields,
  });
```